# Finitely generated submodule of $p$-adic module is direct summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, p-adic-number-theory

Are finitely generated submodules of a $p$-adic module direct summands?

Comment: Does "$p$-adic" mean a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module?

Comment: Why do you want this to be reopened? A first step towards this would be to answer the question of Matt.

Answer (score 2):

No. The $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module $\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p$ has lots of finite subgroups that cannot be summands because they cannot be divisible.

Comment: And if I add the assumption that the module is finitely generated too?

Comment: @pepa, $p\mathbf{Z}_p$ cannot be a direct summand of $\mathbf{Z}_p$. All the submodules of latter intersect non-trivially with $p\mathbf{Z}_p$.